# Combine two shapes

Tags: python, fiona

I'd like to combine the country and the US states data into a single shape. `fiona.open` supports only one file for opening. Is there any way to combine many shapes into one and work with single collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape files are typically used to link a 'layer' of geographic data with other information (population, average rainfall, population of racoons).  As such it does not lend itself to having overlapping geographic data in the same file.  You should check out [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) As a tool (Python Based) that would allow you to create and modify the shapefiles into the format you need.  For example you can take your US STATES shapefiles, import it into QGIS, Merge all of the boundaries and export a new shapefile.  If you still want to merge your shapefiles, check out these questions in [GIS.Stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=merge%20shapefiles)

Comment: Actually you're right. I figured it would be easier to work with them as two separate shapes and have separate layers on the map instead. Thanks!